# Using devise for session management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to conduct user auth through say httparty and do session management through devise? How would I accomplish this because I don't have a users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need devise for session-management. Rails already has [good support](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) for session-management out of the box, which is likely to be adequate for your use-case.

To answer your specific question, much of devise functionality is centered around availability of a User model, so using devise without a User model will not make much sense.

However you can theoritically provide a User model which is not actually backed by a database, but quacks like an ActiveRecord model. This will require quite a bit of effort and testing, but will allow you to reuse the controller extensions, views, mailer integration etc. provided by devise.

But in my opinion, the amount of effort required in the above is not justifiable, and I would recommend building up better familiarity with session management in rails, and build a custom solution that integrates with your authentication service. It is not difficult and likely to be more maintenable.